# How could i handle the multiple foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables two tables User and Favorite.

I want to make a User row to have multiple foreign keys from Favorite

User

```
ID|Name |favorite
1 | tom |1&2 ??? (tom likes cookie and donuts)
2 | max |2&3 ??? (max likes donuts and peanuts)
3 | john|1&2&3 ??? (john likes cookie, donuts and peanuts)
```

Favorite

```
ID | name
1  |cookie
2  |donuts
3  |peanuts
```

What kind of structure is the best for this purpose?
I think this question is basic.
I have made foreign key structure many times though,,,,,

I am using mysql 
and want to know the way to do this on doctrine2 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a many-to-many relationship table

User_Favorite
UserId
FavoriteId

Those two ids will make a composite Primary Key.  And each will be a foreign key to the table they relate to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a third many to many relationship table that will contain:

> User_ID, Favourite_ID

Essentially, you want a many to many relationship: a user has zero to many favorites. A favorite has zero to many users. The correct way to do this is to have a third table consisting of a foreign key referencing the two table primaries (user_id, favouriablete_id). You can remove the favorite column from user table. It is not recommended to use delimited lists to replace many to many.

Comment: Essentially, you want a many to many relationship: a user has zero to many favorites. A favorite has zero to many users. The correct way to do this is to have a third table consisting of a foreign key referencing the two table primaries (user_id, favouriablete_id). You can remove the favorite column from user table. It is not recommended to use delimited lists to replace many to many.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create 3 table 1st for user 2nd for favourite and 3rd for user and favourite relation.
Hence 1st table will be

```
ID|Name 
1 | tom 
2 | max 
3 | john
```

Second table will be as it is

third table will be

```
id|nameid|favouriteid
 1|1     |1
 2|1     |2
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another table called `UserFavorite` and then here store the `Id` of both User and Favorite:
`UserFavorite`

```
UserId | FavoriteId
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a many-to-many relationship for this. To do this, you need an extra table: user2favs or somthing that stores:

```
ID|userid|favid
1 |1     |1
2 |1     |2
3 |2     |2
4 |2     |3
```

etcetera.